# Using Vue component inside blade file with vitejs and laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade, vite

I'm a beginner in VueJS and I wonder how to use a vuejs component from my home.blade.php for example.
Here is my code (I use ViteJS and not Mix)

Card.vue

```html
<template>
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
    <p>Id : {{ filmId }}</p>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['filmId']
    }
</script>
```

app.js

```js
import './bootstrap';
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from './App.vue';

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

And my home.blade.php :

```html
    <div id="app">

        <Card />

    </div>

    @vite('./resources/js/app.js')
```

Comment: What is the issue? Is it not working? Do you have any errors in the browser console?

Comment: nothing in the dev tool, the component is just not loaded

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can't use vue components inside of blade files.

If you're using vue, you use vue for ALL of your views.

The only blade file would be your template which loads vue via vite.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to use Vue components inside blade? The server-side rendering is done and then on the client-side any Vue component is loaded. It seems to me like this could be an issue with component registration:

https://vuejs.org/guide/components/registration.html